# javascript regular expression get string after matched pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

`var str = "fname=peter lname=pan  age=12"`

What I need is to get an array of string, each of that string goes right after fname or lname or age, out of **str** variable. The result is like this: `['peter', 'pan', '12']`.

Could you suggest me an effective solution to accomplish that task (I got a long one, and believe me you would never wanna see that)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var arr = [];
str.replace(/=(\w+)/g, function( a,b ) {
  arr.push( b );
});

console.log( arr ); //=> ["peter", "pan", "12"]
```

Here's another way to do it with similar regex:

```
var arr = str.match(/=\w+/g).map(function( m ){
  return m.replace('=','');
});
```

Comment: This is a better way to do it, using regexp is always more efficient and more clean than using split method and for cycles. Just make sure to return the matched string `b` at the end of the function if you don't want to modify the `str` variable.

Comment: `replace` doesn't mutate the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `regex`.

```
var str = "fname=peter lname=pan age=12";

str = str.split(' ');
for(var i = 0, length = str.length; i < length; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i].split('=')[1];
}
console.log(str); // ['peter', 'pan', '12']
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sRUpM/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider hardcoding the keys to avoid looping:

```
var s   = "fname=peter lname=pan age=12"
var pat = /fname=(\w+)\s*lname=(\w+)\s*age=(\w+)/

r.match(pat)
//returns ["fname=peter lname=pan age=12", "peter", "pan", "12"]
```